# Remove Magento cookies on customer logout not woking

Tags: php, magento, cookies

I'm using an observer and this hook `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_logout`

on customer logout I wish for all set cookies to be deleted, but for some reason they continue to be present after customer logout, I'm certain the code is correct? any ideas?

```
public function deleteCookies(){
    $cookies = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get();

    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $name = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get($cookie);
        $path = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->getPath($cookie);
        $lifetime = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->getLifetime($cookie);

        Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->delete($name, $path, $lifetime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the third parameter of the `delete` function is not the lifetime of the cookie.

```
public function delete($name, $path = null, $domain = null, $secure = null, $httponly = null)
```

try this:

```
public function deleteCookies(){
    $cookies = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie')->get();

    foreach($cookies as $cookieName) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie')->delete($cookieName);
    }
}
```

hope that helps